# Is data representation typically part of a "distributed application middleware"?

Tags: middleware, dataformat

I am currently building a lightweight application layer which provides distributed services to applications of a specific type. This layer provides synchronization and data transmission services to applications which use that layer via an API. Therefore I classify this software as "middleware", since it bridges communication among heterogeneous distributed applications of a specific type. However, my software does not cover data representation. It therefore "only" delivers messages to other applications in a synchronized manner, but does not specify how messages look like and how they can be parsed/read/interpreted/or whatever. Instead, the developer should decide what message format he may use, e.g. JSON, XML, Protobuf, etc. The applications are most of the times governed by one developer party. Now, my question is, whether this is a severe "feature-lack" for being classified as a "distributed application middleware". The aim of the software is to glue together some heterogeneous software applications, where the software type cannot be compared to conventional software and therefore needs specific type of services (which prevents the user to "simply" use CORBA, etc.).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you leave the concrete message format open, you still have specified what formats (JSON, XML) can be used (whether hardcoded or by other means). Therefore in my opinion you have specified data representation.

If your software is modular in adding new formats, then that modularity itself is a feature (and not a lack of a feature).

Comment: The only specification I make for a message is that it is built out of bytes, which can represent anything, in any wire format. It can be JSON, XML,... . However, my concern is that this can be a knock-out-criteria, since developers have to decide what format to use, and therefore (albeit not the aim of this software), in principle can be a problem of gluing together software which already have been interfaced to my "middleware" by other developer teams, since they could not only use different message formats, but a different technology (JSON/XML). So my concern is more whether this is enough.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the developers specify the format (and technology as you call) they want to send data in to you middleware. Then that data can be parsed according to the specification made by the developer. Am I correct?

Comment: Then you must have specified a format in your middleware in which the developers specify their specification. That is your data representation and a feature.

Comment: You mean something like an "interface definition language" (CORBA/RMI)? Then no. The only restriction I make to use the my software for sending a message to some other application is that the message is a "byte array". There is no "contract" between the my software and the application of what this byte array should be. Therefore the receiving application cannot get any guarantees by my software of what the received message is and how it can be read. You can think of sockets and JSON, where sockets stands for my software which only knows about bytes.

Comment: While talking with you about it, I recognize that this is indeed a feature lack, since the specification is not restrictive enough to give any guarantees about the data, which would be nice, since different platforms should not know anything about others. If only byte arrays are used, then this would be a necessary point.

Comment: Exactly. Using your socket example: If you send a JSON-String to socket an application, that is expecting XML, is listening on, that application might crash. You should really include some way for the data to be parsed by your middleware (from input to output data. You can keep the byte arrays, but should at least include some type of headers in the input data which specify some conversion or at least checking method, for your mw to check if the input data does match the expected output data.